# Add name in the ordered list

Tags: jquery

Goal:
Add the name (the name that has even number in the `arraylist`) in the ordered list.

Problem:
How should I do it with jQuery's `each` syntax? you also need to take account to even number.

The array list also can be increased in the future.

---

```
var arrayTask = new Array();
arrayTask[0] = "aaa";
arrayTask[1] = 10;
arrayTask[2] = "bbb";
arrayTask[3] = 11;
arrayTask[4] = "bbb";
arrayTask[5] = 12;
arrayTask[6] = "ccc";

<OL id="test">
<LI>
<LI>
<LI>
<LI>
<LI>
<LI>        
<LI>
<LI>
<LI>
</OL>
```

Comment: The sample `<ol>` has `<li>` elements already, and is **not** showing your desired results.  Are the `li`s to be added or overwritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of iterating the array and generating new LI items for even indexes.

```
// Loop over each value in the array.
$.each(
arrayTask,
function( intIndex, objValue ){
if(intIndex % 2 == 0) // test for even
{
$('#test').append($( "<li>" + objValue + "</li>" ));
}
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(arrayTask, function(index, value){
   if(index%2 == 0)
      $("#test").append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
var counter = 0;
$("#test li").each(function() {
   if(counter % 2 == 0) {
      $(this).text(arrayTask[counter]);
   }
   counter++;
});
```